# ¿Como evitar que se cierre la sesión al cerrar el navegador?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Como puedo lograr que la sesión se mantenga activa siempre, a menos que el usuario la cierre.

Pongo un ejemplo de como le hago.

Hice esto para lograr eso, pero al parecer no funciona:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user'] !== false) {
setCookie("session", $_SESSION['user'], time()+365*24*60*60);
}
```

Y al cerrar sesion:

```
setCookie("session", $_SESSION['user'], time()-365*24*60*60);
```

Comment: Creo que esto lo podrías hacer con una cookie. y cuando el usuario cierre la sesión esta se elimine. Como acotación sería genial que coloques que haz intentado.

Comment: ya lo intente y no me funciono. :/ cree una cookie que se renueva constantemente y ni así.

Comment: No relacionado directamente con la pregunta en sí: ¿qué medidas de seguridad estás tomando para evitar el robo de sesión por cookie?

Comment: Solo puse un ejemplo, no publico el script real por motivos de seguridad. Pero ten por seguro que empleo un sistema de seguridad fiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función `session_start` es la que crea y mantiene la sesión. La información interna de la sesión no conviene pasarla en cookies (`session_start` ya se encarga de mandar una cookie con un `session_id` para eso).

Para aumentar los tiempos hay que pasarle opciones a `session_start`.

```
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => 86400,
]);
```

En el ejemplo las sesiones duran un día `cookie_lifetime` se usa para indicar la vida de la cookie que contiene el `session_id` y con `gc_maxlifetime` el tiempo de limpieza de los `session_id` dentro del servidor.

### Respecto a la validación de las sesiones

Las sesiones con `session_start` se crean cuando se llama a la función y están activas aunque el usuario no se haya logueado (o autenticado). Es tu responsabilidad grabar dentro de los datos de la sesión (ej: `$_SESSION['user']`  y/o `$_SESSION['rol']`, etc) la información sobre si el usuario está logueado o no, quién es, qué permisos tenía al momento de loguearse, etc.

Poner esa información en cookies no es aconsejable.